# Casting map types

Tags: go

I'm trying to write a general function to get the keys of a map like so:

```
func MapKeys(theMap map[interface{}]interface{}) ([]interface{},error) {

    if theMap == nil {
        return nil,errors.New("MapKeys arg is nil")
    }

    var keys = make([]interface{}, len(theMap), len(theMap))

    i := 0
    for idx,_ := range theMap {
        keys[i] = idx
        i++
    }

    return keys, nil
}
```

A) Is there a better way to do this? and B) When calling this function, how do I cast the original map types to map[interface{}]interface{}?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot cast an existing map into a `map[interface{}]interface{}`. You'll have to make use of reflection:

```
func MapKeys(theMap interface{}) ([]interface{}, error) {
    if theMap == nil {
        return nil,errors.New("MapKeys arg is nil")
    }

    v := reflect.ValueOf(theMap) // v is now a reflect.Value type
    if v.Kind() != reflect.Map {
        return nil, errors.New("Argument is not a map")
    }
    var keys = make([]interface{}, v.Len(), v.Len())

    for i, key := range v.MapKeys() {
        keys[i] = key.Interface() // key is also a reflect.Value, key.Interface()
                                  // converts it back into an interface
    }
    return keys, nil
}
```

Working example: https://play.golang.org/p/h9ZfnLHXgX

Comment: I wasn't aware of reflect.Value.MapKeys(). Still learning the basic libs. Thanks!